# I can't get the response from curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I can't get the response from curl in php. Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();

$header = array('api_key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','Content-Type: application/json');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

if($postdata!=""){    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);    
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);  

print_r($response);  // display only 1(one) output not any json   

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got typo here

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Your variable is `$ch`. That'll be correct:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```